# Compiler not Recognizing Control Keys like Return key in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int main() 
 {
     char b;

// the loop is executed until the "Return key" or "Enter" is pressed by the user

     while(b!='\n')
     {
         b=getch();
         putch('*');
     }

     return 0;
}
```

---

The program is something like typing password.As you press alphabets the output displays successive `"*"`s.

Until you press Return key and the program gets finished.
My problem is that my compiler`(Codeblocks 13.12-->GNU GCC)` doesn't understand the control keys like Return.Even when I replace `'\n'` with the ASCII code 10(the concerning ASCII code for Return key) the program makes a mistake again.The mistake is to continue displaying `"*"`s even when Return key is pressed!

What's going on with the compiler and how it 'll be fixed?

Comment: Note that `b` has not been initialised the first time you test it.

Comment: I would suggest to debug it. Look what value b has if you enter the return key.

Comment: Check what your program thinks is receiving by printing `b`.

Comment: can you explain more.How can I solve the problem?

Comment: And there is no `getch` in C. And *certainly* no reason to be bringing in `math.h` :-)

Comment: try initializing b to something before checking it. Comparing an uninitialised variable is undefined behaviour.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the compiler, only with your code.

Comment: Do you mean that I should preset b with some value?for example char b='k'?

Comment: so why the program works for alphabet characters?If i replace control character '\n' with alphabet 'a' the program works correctly.

Comment: Which operating system? It is unrelated to the compiler. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33285027/841108)

Comment: I am working with Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
/* 13 refers to '\r' (carriage return) */
while(b != 13) {
    //Code
}
```